# Pass parameters from Jenkins to C#

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

i have c# nunit testing project, i need to send parameters from the job to the C# test suite.

what i did in my testing code:

```
  string value=  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Name");
```

in the Jenkins side:

[image]

and didn't success to get the value.

any help ?

Thanks

Comment: according to the [EnvInject Plugin docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), you should leave *Properties File Path* empty and set *Properties Content* to: `Name=abcdef`

Answer (score 1):

You can select 'This project is parameterized' checkbox and add required parameter from list.